# Float.MAX_VALUE in java

Tags: java

I was wondering if I write "float f= - Float.MAX_VALUE" in java. It means I got the maximum magnitude in an array and then make the value negative?

I want to find the max and min value of the pixel in an image3D and reduce the min value from the max one. But it seems that the max is somehow negative.. or?!

```
    int[] histo = new int[bins];
    double[] histof = new double[bins];
    float val = 0;
    float max = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = xStart; i <= xEnd; i++) {
        for (int j = yStart; j <= yEnd; j++) {
            for (int k = zStart; k <= zEnd; k++) {
                val = grid.getAtIndex(i, j, k);
                if (val > max) {
                    max = val;
                }
                if (val < min) {
                    min = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    float range = max - min;
    float binSize = range / (float) (bins - 1);


}
```

Comment: It seems that you are very much unclear.

Comment: if you want to know that -Float.MAX_VALUE is the minimum float value then yes its true.

Comment: I only want to know if I add this minus before Float.MAX_VALUE what is that? make the value negative?

Comment: Could you not check it by making a small program.Anyways i have checked it and the answer is yes.

Comment: You have a number `x`. What is `-x` supposed to be other than... `-x`? Also what does any of that has to do with "magnitude in an array"? It's a number.

Comment: 1) why did you dont try it? it is pretty easy.. 2) what about `Math.abs` ? :D of muliple by `-1` ... but abs will be the best :D, maybe not so effective, but best readable

Answer (score 1):

Just try this program to check if it will work or not.

```
class Test2
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        float f=-Float.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

> above program produces a output -3.4028235E38

Comment: this is my code: here i want to find the max and min in an image and reduce the min value from the max value... But the max value seems to be negative..,

Comment: float max = -Float.MAX_VALUE;
  float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
  for (int i = xStart; i <= xEnd; i++) {
   for (int j = yStart; j <= yEnd; j++) {
    for (int k = zStart; k <= zEnd; k++) {
     val = grid.getAtIndex(i, j, k);
     if (val > max) {
      max = val;
     }
     if (val < min) {
      min = val;
     }
    }
   }
  }
  float range = max - min;

Comment: @aziiii what are the elements in the array.

Comment: @aziiii max value will be negative if the array contains all negative numbers.

Comment: @aziiii Please put your code in your question not in the comment to an answer.

Comment: @aziiii edit your question with what you tried. don't put your code in comments.